# RxJava2 + Room: data is not being inserted in DB after clearAllTables() call

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

In my Android application after successful **login** I'm saving session info in Room, then I'm retrieving user information from BE and saving it too.
Everything works fine. I can see saved information in database tables.

When **user logs out** from application all tables are being cleared with appDatabase.clearAllTables() method call.

The catch is that **on subsequent login there's no information that is being inserted in DB** but my Rx calls aren't throwing any errors.

I've tried to use logging and debug but everything looks like normal.

Logging shows following actions being performed: login -> get user info from BE -> save session -> save user.

When debugging I can see that user info is being handled in UserDao_Impl's insertUser() method.

*In application I use RxJava2 version 2.2.2, Room persistence library version 1.1.1, dependencies are being provided with Dagger version 2.19.*

Here's my code snippets:

```
LoginUserUseCase.java

public Completable execute(@NonNull LoginInfo loginInfo) {
    Completable loginAndSaveSession = sessionRepository.loginUser(loginInfo)
                                                    .flatMapCompletable(
                                                            session -> sessionRepository.saveSession(
                                                                    session));
    Completable getAndSaveUserInfo = userRepository.getRemoteUserInfo()
                                                   .flatMapCompletable(
                                                           user -> userRepository.saveUser(
                                                                   user));
    return loginAndSaveSession.andThen(getAndSaveUserInfo);
}
```

---

```
UserRepository.java

public Completable saveUser(@NonNull User user) {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> userDao.insertUser(user));
}
```

---

```
UserDao.java

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertUser(User user);
```

---

```
LogoutUserUseCase.java

public Completable execute() {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> appDatabase.clearAllTables());
}
```

**UPDATE (ISSUE RESOLVED):** wasted a day on this bug. Finally come to understanding that some other library can affect application's work with Room. Turned out that **Android Debug Database library** that I've used to peek inside the database on device **has a [bug](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database/issues/137) that breaks DB after you opened it once with its help**.

Returning back to Stetho.

Comment: Can't figure out how `UserRepository#saveUser()` can return `Completable` if `UserDao#insertUser()` return nothing (void). Do you have special wrapper?

Comment: @ConstOrVar sorry, my bad. Somehow I've lost Completable.fromAction() that wrapped UserDao.insertUser(). Fixed code

Comment: For anyone stumbling to this in future. The Database Inspector from Android Studio under App Inspection has the same issue: ie. if you open the DB inspector in Android studio and a call to `clearAllTables()` was made in the app. The inserting into DB is compromised. Tested on Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Windows 10